# Item in MemoryCache too big?

Tags: c#, memorycache

I'm trying to understand the sizing algorithm of the MemoryCache class in C#.
I was thinking that an item with a short key (a one-character string) and a small value (ie. bool) will occupy a tiny amount of memory, but my tests proved me wrong.

This is the code I used to test it:

```
Console.WriteLine("Mem before creating Cache:" + GC.GetTotalMemory(true).ToString());
MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache("testcache");
Console.WriteLine("Mem after creating Cache:" + GC.GetTotalMemory(true).ToString());

long tinyAvg=0;
int sampleSize = 500;
for (var i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
{
    var memBefore = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    cache.Add(i.ToString() , true, null);
    var memAfter = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    var overhead = memAfter - memBefore;
    tinyAvg += overhead;
    //Console.WriteLine("Mem overhead for adding tiny item:" + overhead.ToString());
}
Console.WriteLine("Average for tiny item: " + tinyAvg / sampleSize);
```

Running this code, I get an average of 129 bytes / item in the cache, which looks to me much too large.

Note that I'm using GC.GetTotalMemory() for profiling. I know it might not give the exact numbers, but a rough estimation is also enough.

Why is the cache item so big for such a small key/value pair? Is there any way of making it smaller?

BTW - I know this is a Micro-Benchmarking, and I know that memory is cheap these days. This is a sample which represents a much larger cache, with huge keys,  millions of items, and limited RAM, so we need to find a solution for this...

Thanks!

Comment: Multiple problems with this approach: 1) A cache isn't just a dictionary, it also needs to keep track of what expires when, how often it's used etc.  2) Containers don't make new allocations each time an item is added. They reserve buffers space in advance and copy their data to a new larger buffer when they reach their capacity. You may be seeing the effects of unused capacity. 3) Whether you store a bool or int, you still use 32 bits. Byte/bit arrays can pack their values but here you are storing to a dictionary

Comment: Run your test code using Visual Studio's memory profiler to see what is really being allocated

Comment: `MemoryCache` has much more overhead then simply storing the values. It also registers to AppDomain events, has performance counters and measures TTL expiry. If you want to know more , [start here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Caching/System/Caching/MemoryCache.cs,907d2d375e58dbee)

Comment: Running the sample under the profiler shows that various structures are generated - Hashtables (to allow searching by key), cache entries (obviously), expiration buckets (to quickly find items to evict), bit vectors (probably to determine whether a specific entry is active or not ?).

Comment: Instead of micro-benchmarking, consider *how* you want to use memory. If you want it as storage for lots of data, use Redis or another in-memory db. If you want to use it for a relatively small amount of lookup data, use a dictionary or array. A *cache* is something that keeps frequently used data in limited memory to avoid expensive queries.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - how would you define a "relatively small amount"? We have millions of records, but no need for complex query. Would you recommend using Dictionary?

Comment: I don't know what you want to build, or why you want to put millions of records in memory. I do know that "put it in memory" isn't the solution to everything - searching in memory uses CPU and *that* can lead to bottlenecks in a web application. Updating in memory requires synchronization, even if you used a ConcurrentDictionary. You could end up going *slower* than if you only loaded the most frequently used entries.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following... Using dictionary, there isn't really a "searching", isn't it? And there won't be other forms of querying / searching.